# How can get around this issue in my image gallery?

Tags: html, class, gallery, image

This is how I have my HTML for the images in my gallery:

```
<p class="crop">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" /></p>
<p class="crop">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" /></p>
```

However, using p classes like this makes them separate images instead of a group of images and therefore my next/previous arrows don't work.

I need to make them a group of images so the arrows in the gallery can work again properly, but I want to keep the p class as I need it to crop the images. How can I get around this?

Comment: test .crop{display:inline;}

Answer (score 0):

Replace the p with 1 div so it would look like:

```
<div class="crop">
<img>
<img>
</div>
```

Add more images as needed (filling in the image data)

In the CSS you can then use:

```
.crop img {}
```

to crop the images!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This makes the arrows work properly again but it causes the images in the gallery to end up on top of each other. What would I need to add to .crop in the CSS to make the images next to each other instead of on top?

Answer (score 0):

Move the crop logic to the img tag

```
<img class="crop" src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" />
<img class="crop" src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" />
```

Comment: This solution did work but for some reason it ended up squashing the images instead of cropping them. Is there anyway I could get around that?