# Image gallery - How to group images using div or p classes

Tags: html, gallery, image

This is how I have my HTML for the images in my gallery:

```
<p class="crop">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" /></p>
<p class="crop">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" /></p>
```

However, using p classes like this makes them separate images instead of a group of images and therefore my next/previous arrows don't work.

I need to make them a group of images so the arrows in the gallery can work again properly, but I want to keep the p class as I need it to crop the images. How can I get around this?

Here is the CSS for the crop class:

```
.crop{
float:left;
display:inline;
margin:2px;
overflow:hidden; /* this is important */
position:relative; /* this is important too */
width:320px;
height:240px;
}
.crop img{
position:absolute;
top:-0px;
left:-0px;
}
```

Here's the link to the question when I asked previously: [How can get around this issue in my image gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556537/how-can-get-around-this-issue-in-my-image-gallery) Unfortunately none of the solutions worked.

Comment: Could you please provide more information. Where are the arrows and how do they work? What do you mean by grouping?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you posted this exact same question an hour or two ago, I take it the  and/or  advice did not achieve the desired result? While I think duplicate questions are frowned on around here, may I suggest at least linking to your previous question so people can inform themselves of previous attempts at answering? I wanted to see your responses to what people already suggested, but can't, because I can't find the original question.

What happened when you tried the previous advice??

NOTE: I realize this isn't an answer, but I needed more information to try to help you, and I don't yet have enough "rep" to post comments on other people's posts. Please don't hold it against me :)

It would also help if you posted your CSS code so we can understand the desired effect.

Comment: I've posted the link to the other question and the CSS. ^_^

Comment: Did you try Hexa's advise? `.crop{display:inline;}` Sorry, yes, I see that's in your CSS that you posted...